# Running a WCF Duplex Web Service Client under a new message loop thread

Tags: c#

I need to run a WCF duplex client connection under a new message loop in a thread, so far I’ve implemented the following:

```
public class RoomOpen
{
    public static bool Main(Data oSystem)
    {
        Thread STA5050Thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            Application.Run();
            var oring = new FXBackgroundLoader(oSystem.GetSystem());

        });

        STA5050Thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        STA5050Thread.IsBackground = true;
        STA5050Thread.Start();

        return true;
    }
}
```

The problems here are:

A - The client connection that should start under FXBackgroundLoader() is never called, this connection is made and then pings sent continually so the thread should start and stay open.

B - The application returns true almost immediately.

What I need in the end is a WCF duplex client connection which can run under a new message loop on the current thread but keep the thread open without blocking it.

One way I've previously had success with is to open a Windows form under Application.Run(new form()) and then pop all the code for the client connection in the form, that works fanatically but is no longer a possibility due to additional changes in my project.

Does anyone have any idea what the issue is with my implementation and/or how I might better implement what I require?